# View not recieving variable from controller Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

As the title says with other controller and view I can send the data but I can't with the controller and view I'm gonna post below.

**Controller code (Its a resource controller but I'm using a custom function)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Persona;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PersonaController extends Controller
{

public function mostrarMedicos(){
    $medicos = Persona::where('idTipoPersona', 4)->get();
    return view('gestionMedicos',compact($medicos));
```

}
}

**View Code**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h1>Gestión Médicos</h1>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr class="info">
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Cedula</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Teléfono</th>
            <th>Dirección</th>
            <th>Ciudad Residencia</th>
            <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
            <th>Género</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($medicos as $medico)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$medico->nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{$medico->apellido}}</td>
                <td>{{$medico->cedula}}</td>
                <td>{{$medico->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$medico->telefono}}</td>
                <td>{{$medico->direccion}}</td>
                <td>{{$medico->ciudadResi}}</td>
                <td>{{$medico->fechaNacimiento}}</td>
                <td>{{$medico->genero}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/gestionarMedicos', [PersonaController::class,'mostrarMedicos'])->name('personaMostrarMedicos');
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Undefined variable $medicos (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\SistemaHNF\resources\views\gestionMedicos.blade.php)
```

Im new on Laravel and I don't understand why I get this error if from what I can understand the controller is supossed to return the view with the `$medicos` variable that should have the data.

(English is not my main language so sorry for any mistake and also I can post any extra code or explain in more detail something if needed).

Comment: return view('gestionMedicos',compact('medicos')); simple just remove $ sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have return query builder and  forgotten to call `get()` or `first()` and also wrong with `compact`

```
public function mostrarMedicos(){
        $medicos = Persona::where('idTipoPersona', 4)->get();
        return view('gestionMedicos',compact('medicos'));
}
```

Comment: already did it but still getting error. Going to update the question to reflect the change

Comment: @DiegoUtreras.you have issue with compact. check my answer again

Comment: yeah that was the iisue @John, thanks for helping. It needs the variable as a String in the compact method, my mistake.